# How to bind variable to a HTML tag in SQL?

Tags: html, sql

How to bind variable to a HTML tag in SQL?

```
SET @body ='<html><body><H3>File loaded successfully at Getdate()</H3></body>'
```

How to concatenate this variable: `Getdate()` to the existing the HTML Tag?

Comment: Which language?  Use PHP or javascript for example...

Comment: Its inside the SQL - Stored Procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the date to a string and concat it:

```
SET @body ='<html><body><H3>File loaded successfully at ' + convert(nvarchar(max), GETDATE(), 0) + '</H3></body>'
```

Comment: @goofyui Use 0 as the parameter instead of 101.  I've edited my answer.  Please accept if useful.